# Questions regarding socketaddress_un

Tags: linux, history, sockets

For Unix Sockets , there is the struct `sockaddress_un` which has two members : `sun_family` which refers to the **communication domain in which the socket is to be created** and `sun_path` which refers to the **path name**

Can someone explain the meaning of the words in bold ??

Why is the rationale for naming the two members : `sun_family` & `sun_path`

What does the `un` in `sockaddress_un` mean ??

Comment: This question is off-topic here and belongs to Stackoverflow instead. It is going to be migrated there in a few hours so you need not open a new question there.

Answer (score 0):

For the communication domain you might want to look at where the macro for AF_UNIX (which is mentioned in `/usr/include/un.h`) is set, using grep -FR AF_UNIX /usr/include/`. On my system`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h` gives:

```
/* Protocol families.  */
#define PF_UNSPEC       0       /* Unspecified.  */
#define PF_LOCAL        1       /* Local to host (pipes and file-domain).  */
#define PF_UNIX         PF_LOCAL /* POSIX name for PF_LOCAL.  */
#define PF_FILE         PF_LOCAL /* Another non-standard name for PF_LOCAL.  */
#define PF_INET         2       /* IP protocol family.  */
#define PF_AX25         3       /* Amateur Radio AX.25.  */
#define PF_IPX          4       /* Novell Internet Protocol.  */
#define PF_APPLETALK    5       /* Appletalk DDP.  */
#define PF_NETROM       6       /* Amateur radio NetROM.  */
#define PF_BRIDGE       7       /* Multiprotocol bridge.  */
#define PF_ATMPVC       8       /* ATM PVCs.  */
#define PF_X25          9       /* Reserved for X.25 project.  */
#define PF_INET6        10      /* IP version 6.  */
#define PF_ROSE         11      /* Amateur Radio X.25 PLP.  */
...
```

Which indicates that the domain is the type of communication that the socket is handling.

The `un` stands for unified as this combines the different additional informations (port number, path, pipe, etc) these different domains use, the specifics of which are passed in the sun_path part of the `struct sockaddr_un`.